# Does this matrix norm inequality imply an inequality of norm on matrices acting on vectors?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If we have for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that
$$\|A\| \leq \|B\|,$$ then do we get for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
|Ax|_2 \leq |Bx|_2?
$$

I'm sorry if this is simple, but I worry that this doesn't hold. Is there as case where
$$
{|Bx| \over |x|} < {|Ax| \over |x|} \land \|A\| \leq \|B\|?
$$
Similarly, if this is the case could any restriction to the matrices make the second inequality hold?

Comment: $\|Ax\|_2\le\|Bx\|_2$ if and only if $x^\ast A^\ast Ax=\|Ax\|_2^2\le\|Bx\|_2^2=x^\ast B^\ast Bx$. Hence the inequality is true for all vectors $x$ if and only if $B^\ast B-A^\ast A$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason it's true. With $n=2$, take for example $A=I$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 0\\
0 & 10
\end{pmatrix}$. One has $\|A\|=1\leq \|B\|$ but $\left|A\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\right|_2=1>\frac{1}{2}=\left|B\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\right|_2$.